# writing to command prompt using assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I've been trying to write to CMD so that I will be able to concatenate WAV files using SOX. Therefore, I need to write to CMD from my program (written in assembly 8086)and create a concatenated file. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean write to stdout. Yes, that is of course possible. It's unclear what `sox` has to do with it. Also I would be rather surprised if it had a 16 bit port.

Comment: Are you asking about sending *commands* to the shell, i.e. running other programs from your 16-bit executable?  If your 16-bit program runs inside DOSBOX, it can't start stuff outside DOSBOX.  (And 16-bit executables can't run natively under a 64-bit kernel.)  So either you need a 16-bit SOX, or you need to run your 16-bit program under 32-bit Windows, if I'm guessing correctly about what you want to do.

Comment: What does “write to CMD” mean for you?  I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I mean writing a command in my program to use the shell and create a new file (the concatenated WAV).

Comment: @D.Gash Ah I see! Look up Int 21/AH=4Bh “[EXECUTE PROGRAM](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2939.htm).” That's the DOS call you need to invoke an external program.

Comment: But how can I write a command in the program so it will be executed in CMD?